# Matlab: Error using readtable (line 216) Input must be a row vector of characters or string scalar

Tags: matlab

I gave the error `Error using readtable (line 216) Input must be a row vector of characters or string scalar` when I tried to run this code in Matlab:

```
clear
close all
clc
D = 'C:\Users\Behzad\Desktop\New folder (2)';
filePattern = fullfile(D, '*.xlsx');
file = dir(filePattern);
x={};
for k = 1 : numel(file)
    baseFileName = file(k).name;
    fullFileName = fullfile(D, baseFileName);
    x{k} = readtable(fullFileName);
    fprintf('read file %s\n', fullFileName);
end
% allDates should be out of the loop because it's not necessary to be in the loop
dt1 = datetime([1982 01 01]);
dt2 = datetime([2018 12 31]);
allDates = (dt1 : calmonths(1) : dt2).';
allDates.Format = 'MM/dd/yyyy';
% 1) pre-allocate a cell array that will store
%   your tables (see note #3)
T2 = cell(size(x)); % this should work, I don't know what x is
% the x is xlsx files and have different sizes, so I think it should be in
% a loop?
% creating loop
for idx = 1:numel(x)
    T = readtable(x{idx});
    % 2) This line should probably be T = readtable(x(idx));
    sort = sortrows(T, 8);
    selected_table = sort (:, 8:9);
    tempTable = table(allDates(~ismember(allDates,selected_table.data)), NaN(sum(~ismember(allDates,selected_table.data)),size(selected_table,2)-1),'VariableNames',selected_table.Properties.VariableNames);
    T2 = outerjoin(sort,tempTable,'MergeKeys', 1);
    % 3) You're overwriting the variabe T2 on each iteration of the i-loop.
    % to save each table, do this
    T2{idx} = fillmissing(T2, 'next', 'DataVariables', {'lat', 'lon', 'station_elevation'});

end
```

the x is each xlsx file from the first loop. my xlsx file has a different column and row size. I want to make the second loop process for all my xlsx files in the directory.
did you know what is the problem? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Readtable has one input argument, a filename. It returns a table. In your code you have the following:

```
x{k} = readtable(fullFileName);
```

All fine, you are reading the tables and storing the contents in x. Later in your code you continue with:

```
T = readtable(x{idx});
```

You already read the table, what you wrote is basically `T = readtable(readtable(fullFileName))`. Just use `T=x{idx}`

Comment: Oh, thank you, you are right. I fixed the problem but new error appeared:
`Subscripting a table using linear indexing (one subscript) or
multidimensional indexing (three or more subscripts) is not
supported. Use a row subscript and a variable subscript.`

Comment: A table always expects 2 indices, one for row, one for column. Somewhere in your code you are using 1 or more than 2 indices. The error message should indicate the line.